# Can I use Realm + Parceler with public attribute ( without getter / setter)?

Tags: java, android, realm, parceler

It seems that if I don't generate the getters and setters for my RealmObject and send it to another activity using Parceler, all the attributes are reset to their default value.

Is there a way to avoid creating these getters and setters and keep the values?

Thanks.

Comment: If it's a managed realmObject then consider requerying it in the other activity based on its primary key

Comment: Unfortunately, It's an unmanaged object because I also want to use two-way data binding. I think what I'm trying to do is poorly designed and I need to refactor.

Comment: I see, make sure you DON'T specify Serialization.BEAN, but you also probably don't need analyze either

Comment: Removing Serialization.BEAN and analyze did the trick. I can now use Parceler without getter/setter and I still have the value I have set. I will spend more time on the documentation to really understand what that change means.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: It means it won't try to use getters/setters for serialization (BEAN) but it won't consider its implementation (analyze), I made the assumption that you don't try to parcel managed objects.

Comment: Once again thank you for your explanation. It's my first question on SO, should I 'close' the question somehow?

Comment: I posted it as an answer, this way you can accept it with the tick thing on the side :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you DON'T specify Serialization.BEAN, but you also probably don't need analyze either.

It means it won't try to use getters/setters for serialization (BEAN) but it won't consider its implementation (analyze), I made the assumption that you don't try to parcel managed objects.